# Command line user does not have read and write permissions on generated directory. Magento ver 2.3 cloud environment

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, file-permissions

I am using Magento cloud.

When I try to run `setup:di:compile` command in one of my development branch. I am getting

> Command line user does not have read and write permissions on
>   generated directory. Please address this issue before using Magento
>   command line.

So I tried to give a folder & file permission for the generated folder in the root directory. I got this error

> chmod: changing permissions of 'generated': Read-only file system

How to solve this issue?

Comment: which user your using to run the cmds

Comment: I can see the user is "web"

Comment: I was guided by an magento cloud expert "You can't run any of those commands on the servers. Any of the commands that modify files other than cache files have to be run as part of the deploy process. There's no way to change permissions or create new users with different permissions on the Magento Cloud servers"